# ParserException in Protege SWRL rule editor on swrlb:greaterThan

Tags: protege, swrl

I am using Protege 4.3 and SWRL to make some rules with Pellet as a reasoner.

I am trying to use the SWRL builtins but i cannot make it work at all.

The rule is correct but Protege does not seem to recognise at all the builtin (e.g. swrlb:greaterThan)

Could you inform me on the process necessary to make Protege 4.3 identify the SWRL builtins?

Here is an example of a rule:

```
Asset(?p), id(?p, ?x), swrlb:greaterThan(?x, 10) -> State(?p)
```

My problem is that it doesn't seem to recognize at all the `swrlb:greaterThan`. The error says:

> OWLRuntimeException: org.protege.editor.owl.model.classexpression.OWLExpressionParserException: Encountered swrlb:greaterThan at line 1 column 30.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Protégé (4.2.0, anyways, but I'd expect the same is true for 4.3), you don't need to add the prefix `swrlb:` in the editor.  Just use `greaterThan`.  For instance, if you type this in the editor:

[image: rule editor]

you'll get:

[image: the rendered rule]

Answer (score 0):

Class: State

```
id some xsd:int[> "10"^^xsd:int]
```

Currently Protege (I'm using the v 5.5.0) doesn't support swrlb on reasoning (Hermit, Pellet, ...). You can:

- create a class "State"
- add an "EquivalentTo" rule like above in the "State class"
- run the reasoner

You should now see the entities with id>10 with "State" in the Types list